# Does there exist a formula?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How would one evaluate the following:

$\Pi^n_{i=1} (\sqrt{i}-4)$

Is there any formula? Or do we have to compute the product manually for any given value of $n<=15$.

Comment: Well, for any $n>=16$ the product is zero since it contains $\sqrt{16}-4 = 0$.  So there are only at most 15 terms to compute.

Comment: Yeah. What if n<=15?